# Different optimization behavior using np.random-normal instead of tf.random_normal

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, random, neural-network

I’m looking into the code from https://github.com/AshishBora/csgm and experience some strange behavior when using np.random.normal instead of `tf.random_normal` as initializing of a `tf.Variable`. More concrete: 
Instead of

```
z = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((batch_size, hparams.n_z)), name='z')
```

I have

```
# in mnist_vae/src/model_def.py, line 74
z = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(batch_size, 
                hparams.n_z)).astype('float32'), name='z')
```

z is the variable, which is optimized via Adam optimizer with respect to an objective.

For a little bit background: There is a pre-trained neural network G, whose input z is drawn from a standard normal distribution using tf.random_normal. For a given `z*`, one wants to solve `ẑ= argmin_z ||AG(z)-AG(z*)||` and check the reconstruction error `||G(ẑ)-G(z*)||`. The outcoming minimal value `c(z*)=||G(ẑ)-G(z*)||` is for several different `z*` quite stable around a value c1. Now, I wasn’t quite sure whether the optimization (Adam optimizer) might use the information that z comes from a standard normal distribution. So I replaced the `tf.random_normal` by a `np.random_normal` in the hope that the optimizer can’t use the information then. (see the code above)

Unfortunately, the results are indeed different using `np.random.normal: c(z*)=||G(ẑ)-G(z*)||` is for several different `z*` stable around a different value `c2` (not `c1`). How can one explain this? Is it really that the optimizer uses the information of the normal distribution (e.g. as loglikelihood prior) in the optimization? My feeling says no, since it's only the initialization.

The code is given in https://github.com/AshishBora/csgm

Comment: The Adam optimizer in TensorFlow cannot "use" the fact that some value was initialized from a normal distribution in any way. The only difference is that the actual random values will be different in each case. Is it possible that you are optimizing for the same single value z* on each trial?

Comment: Ok, this is a good confirmation that it the optimizer doesn't change its performance. But the question then is, why the results are so different.
The reconstruction value c(z*) is computed for 64 randomly drawn z* and then meaned to get c1. This value is quite stable around c1, when repeating the computation for 64 newly drawn z*.
But when using the numpy random variable, the meaned value is also stable (when drawing 64 new z*), but around a value ten times as large as c1.